# ffmpeg build - uknown temp folder

Tags: build, ffmpeg, compiler-errors, gnu-make

Hi

Can anyone to help me about this error when i build ffmpeg-3.4.1 with gnu under windows :

```
/tmp/9747a756ee05ef34cc3fcf51eabde826/sysroot/usr/include/unistd.h:173: error: undefined reference to '__page_size'
```

I set temp folder manually but **GNU-Make** tries to find above path.

My own guess is that gnu cannot create temp files and folders in Windows %TEMP% directory.

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you following the [compilation guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide#Windows), if so which one.

Comment: It doesn't TRY to find above path, it DOES find the path and encounters an error inside the header file. The error happens inside the actual file, not while trying to find it.

Comment: To [aergistal] >> Project is compiled with MinGW. Not completely follow compiling guides!

Comment: To [TheSHEEEP] >> When i go to tmp address there is no such a path and header file 'unistd.h'

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I found the problem was referred to android-ndk version.

Changing to from **ndk-r14b** to **ndk-r10** fixed the issue!